# Why don't we use tags on the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I noticed on blogoverflow, all of the posts for the blog are filed under 'uncategorized'. Is there a reason for this? *Can* we categorize them? *Should* we categorize them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly this is just a "we just haven't".

We can categorize and we might consider doing it in the future and going back and adding tags and categories and what not in the future.

However, SEI is considering taking their blogging operation in house and I'm not sure what that will look like. Until I'm sure we're staying on Wordpress for the future I'm not concerned enough about it to go back and retag stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think we've been fairly consistent in tagging stuff, we don't categorize stuff.  Tags are usually:

> ([Denomination], [Topic])

I think we would if we could, but that's because waxeagle is too lazy to make up categories :D and how would they be distinct from the tags anyway?

The other problem is that we can't edit our posts after they've been published, so since we're reliant on the good will of wax and starman we're (or at least I'm) a little hesitant to just ask them to fix something like that if I've forgotten.